# Spring xml config enable @Async without @Scheduled

Tags: xml, spring, spring-java-config

Using Spring's xml configuration, how can I enable scanning of `@Async` annotations without also enabling scanning of `@Scheduled` annotations?

Normally, you would enable both simultaneously using `<task:annotation-driven />` but I'm trying to enable scheduling only when a particular Spring profile is active.

Using Spring JavaConfig, you can use `@EnableAsync` and `@EnableScheduling` separately. I'm maintaining a project that's been around for a few years and uses only xml and annotation based config and I don't want to add JavaConfig to the mix unless it's the only way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the namespace add the respective beans manually. The `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` takes care of `@Async` and `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` takes care of `@Scheduled`.

By registering the beans manually you can simply move the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to the profile where you want it active.