# Spring MVC : Asynchronous giving beancurrently in creation exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I want to use @Async at-least for the methods which are fire-and-forget. When I try to use @Async and I have used @EnableAsync annotation too for class, the actions inside the method are not performed. When I add task executor in servlet-context.xml, then I get an error bean is getting currently created. I am new to Async, can anyone tell me how I can use it. 
I am not using Eager loading btw. 
Error log :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupNotesService': Bean with name 'groupNotesService' has been injected into other beans [mattachService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

Code  : 
GroupNotesServiceImpl :

```
@Service
@Transactional
@EnableAsync
public class GroupNotesServiceImpl implements GroupNotesService {

 @Override
    @Async
    public void editGroupNote(GroupNotes mnotes, int msectionId) {
//Code to be executed, which is not getting executed
    }

}
```

Servlet-context.xml :

```
 <task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="20"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/" />
```

If I remove any of the mvc lines above, I get a servlet.init() threw load exception error.

Also, Is it possible to use Async where I am returning int? I checked out the Future tag, but I don't know what modifications are required.
Here is the method that returns int.

```
 @Override
    public int saveGroupNoteAndReturnId(GroupNotes mnotes, int msectionid) {
  // saves note and returns its id.
}
```

MattachService bean :

```
<beans:bean id="mattachDAO"
        class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupAttachmentsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mattachService"
        class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupAttachmentsDAO" ref="mattachDAO" />
    </beans:bean>
```

*Edit* 
I checked out that there is a problem to run @Transactional and @Async both in one class. Jira SPR-7147. The workaround suggested there was to introduce a normal facade, and I really don't know what that means.

Comment: Please share the code for `mattachService` bean.

Comment: @Mithun : I have added it. Check it out.

Comment: P.S : I tried using default lazy-init=true, that didn't help.

Comment: Incase anyone requires the entire servlet-context, http://pastebin.com/bu1uFNJT

Comment: If it's feasible, please create a simple project to simulate this error and add it to github. This will help in resolving the issue faster.

Comment: @Mithun : Unfortunately I cannot. All of the parts are important.

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableAsync` should be in configuration, not the service itself. Since you seem to use xml configuration, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127051/562721. It recommends to declare `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to take care of `@Async` annotations

Comment: Where should I declare it? Can you give me XML corrections. I don't have any file with @Configuration by the way. I just have @ Controller, @ Service, @ Model, @ Repository.

Comment: You can try `<task:annotation-driven>`. See  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Already tried that, when I do that, I get servlet.init() error.  Error is : Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location. I also tried giving a executor, that also does not help.